# How to set "parindent" in the reference section?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, csquotes

Can somebody help me? I want my reference to meet the following standard of an article as follows:

```
\textbf{References}

{\leftskip=2em\parindent=-2em

Anderson, C. A., Gentile, D. A., {\&} Buckley, K. E. (2007).
\emph{Violent video game effects on children and adolescents:
Theory, research and public policy.}
https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780195309836.001.0001

}
```

[image]

however I can't figure out how to set it through my preamble

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
```

.....

```
\addbiresource{myfile.bib}
```

.....

```
@Article{siraj,
author = {{Siraj-ul-Islam} and I. Aziz and B. Sarler},
title = {The numerical solution of second-order boundary-value problems by collocation method with the Haar wavelets},
journal = {Mathematical and Computer Modelling},
year = {2010},
volume = {52},
pages = {1577-1590},
doi = {10.1016/j.mcm.2010.06.023}
}
```

the outcome in  the reference does not meet the indent required in the second line.

this is the all code

---

```
\documentclass[twoside,10.5pt]{article}%                        *
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%                                          *
\usepackage{pifont}%                                            *
\usepackage{amsmath}%                                           *
\usepackage{amsthm}%                                            *
\usepackage{txfonts}%                                           *
 \usepackage{geometry}%                                         *
\usepackage{latexsym}%                                          *
\usepackage{amssymb}%                                           *
\usepackage{graphicx}%                                          *
\usepackage{geometry}%                                          *
\usepackage{enumitem}%
\usepackage{ifthen}%                                            *
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%                                          *
\usepackage{afterpage}%                                         *
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%                                            *
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \setlength{\parskip}{5pt}%          *
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}%                           *
\usepackage{ifthen}%                                            *
\geometry{paperheight=28.5cm,paperwidth=21cm,top=2.5cm,%        *
bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,headsep=0.4cm,headheight=1.5cm,%  *
footskip=1.1cm}%                                                *
%%***************************************************************
\usepackage{titlesec}%                                          *
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.3em}{}%       *
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}%                         *
\titleformat{\subsection}{\itshape}{\thesubsection}{0.3em}{}%   *
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}%                      *
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\rmfamily}%                        *
{\thesubsubsection}{0.3em}{}%                                   *
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}%                   *
%%***************************************************************

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\bfx}{{\bf x}}
\def\ds{\displaystyle}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rand}{rand}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
 bla bla bla .....

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

the reference was set manually like this

```
\textbf{References}

{\leftskip=2em\parindent=-2em
....
}
```

but as I have a huge file.bib, I replace to be automatic to refer any article anywhere with ease.

Comment: Can you complete the code so people can compile it?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want, but the hanging indent for `biblatex` is set by the length `\bibhang`, so in your preamble `\setlength{\bibhang}{...}` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In author-year-like bibliography styles the indent of subsequent lines of an entry is controlled by `\bibhang`. It looks like you want to set that length to `2em`.

The space between entries is controlled by `\bibitemsep`. Judging by the screenshot you may also want to increase that from its (author-year) default `0pt`.

```
\documentclass[twoside,10.5pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Indented and separated bibliography.]